# telnet localhost 1433 failed

Tags: sql-server, telnet

I issued this command on the command line:

```
telnet localhost 1433.
```

And I got this message:

> Can not connect host, port 1433..

I tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 1433` too.

I checked:

1. In SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration >
   Protocols for MSSQLSERVER > TCP/IP > STATUS IS SET TO "USE"

[image]

2. Checked for firewall, and the firewall is off
3. Tried to see if the port for 1433 is opend : `netstat -an | find"1433"` in the command line.

And the result is as below and I don't know what it means...
Seems the port for 1433 is opened.

[image]

I need your help, please tell me why I can't connect SQL Server...

Comment: That certainly indicates something is listening on the port. Firewall has no bearing if you are connecting locally. Are you using telnet because you are troubleshooting database connectivity?

Comment: @Eun, this is usually resolved by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502714/intermittent-odbc-connection-failures/52504914#52504914)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open firewall for port 1433.

Go to Windows Firewall and add new inbound rule for port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. There were 2 sql servers hosting on my pc: MSSQLSERVER and SQLEXPRESS. Just set different ports for them.